# ionic using popTo specifc page

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am using ionic2.

I need popTo specific page.

If the user orders the products Need to authenticated.So going to SigninPage.

I passed the query params in nav.push.user after signin.

Here is my code

```
this.navCtrl.push('CustomershippingPage',{Page:'Signin'});
```

.
Going to CustomershippingPage.

If user go to back click nav backbutton.

I Check the query params value is Signin and page is pop to cartPage

Here is my code.

I tried to this

```
this.navCtrl.popToRoot('CartPage');
```

But i am getting this err

```
Cannot create property 'direction' on string 'CartPage'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adjust your code to this

check and make sure your app.html looks like this by adding `#content`

> app.html

```
 <ion-nav [root]="rootPage" #content></ion-nav>
```

> yourpage.ts

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, Content } from 'ionic-angular';

...
export class YourTestPage{

   @ViewChild("content") nav: NavController;


   yourmethod(){
     this.nav.setRoot('CartPage');
   }

}
```

Comment: .Thanks for ur reply.I have one doubt may I ask u?

Comment: It's work.Actually,nav.pop() is goto previouspage is right.How can change previouspage component.

Comment: Don't forget to mark this as your answer. for your second question - this.navCtrl.pop() will take you to previous page on the stack. But how do you mean changing the component. What exactly do u expect to happen.

Comment: Thanks for ur patient.I update my question kindly check it.